# How do I create responsive images that resize with different mobile phone sizes?

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

A mobile site I'm working on https://lowlifeclothing.co/ has every .gif image placed perfectly on  my iPhone 11 Pro Max where I have been beta testing, but on smaller screen resolutions the images move drastically and ruin the design of the site.

You can see what I mean by changing the phone type/ resolution size of the site here; https://bluetree.ai/screenfly/?u=https%3A//lowlifeclothing.co&a=20&b=10

The site resembles an old school deer hunter game and the code I'm using for the deer animations is as follows;

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#image1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12D.gif");
    var url = $(this).attr("data-click-href");
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = url;
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12.gif" data-click-href="https://lowlifeclothing.co/shop/" id="image1">
```

How can I get the deer images, button & menu to remain in the same place on every mobile device?

I've used margin and padding to position them so they fit perfectly when I beta test on an iPhone 11 Pro Max, but they move drastically with different screen resolutions, say on an iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use JS to resize images responsively.
Simply use CSS perspective width/height percentage to size it correctly.
Usually, when developing mobile websites, images that you want to be fixed on the whole width of the device will be centered with `width: 90vw;`.

Maybe this will help you: https://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Answer (score 0):

use this :

width:100% and height: 100%

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```